# How to remove it items from one Excel list, if the same item exist in different list

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I know nothing about Excel, so the first thing I would like to do is to remove any duplicates from within the lists themselves.

But then I would also like any rows from list B that has a duplicate row in list A to be removed.

For example, if the email `John@John.com` is in list B and there is also a `John@john.com` in list A, I want to remove `John@john.com` from list B.

[image: here is a pic of situation/problem]

Comment: When you add a screenshot make always sure, your screenshot doesn't contain any sensible data and show dummy data instead - the one provided seems to be not really made for *public eyes*...

Comment: I don't have a full answer to this, but you can remove duplicates from one sheet using **Data > Remove Duplicates** (inside Data Tools).

Comment: Sorry, this is somewhat of a public list, and I did try to make sure that there wasn't any complete info. but in the future, I will try to do something else

Comment: It's alright. It will probably don't harm anyone, but just for the future it might be good. Not everyone will like to find data of him like this in public place :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### To remove the duplicates:

1. Select the range of cells, or make sure that the active cell is in a table.
2. On the **Data** tab, in the **Data Tools** group, click **Remove Duplicates**.[image]

### To remove duplicates form list A in list B:

`=IF(COUNTIF(ListB!$A:$A;ListA!A1)>0;"";ListB!A1)`

First of all, you need to make a new sheet `ListC` For example, 
This is what you should paste into ListC at A1 and pull it down across.
Of course you'll have to change `ListA!` & `ListB!` by the names of your sheets.

Comment: [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXyOf.jpg

Comment: It's saying there's a problem with the formula. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: That's true, my mistake, this function works if you put it in a new sheet `ListC`for example